# Hadoop Path is not a file

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and trying out the sample program of wordcount already distributed with hadoop installation. I have created input directory named as "input" in hdfs and it contains my pdf file (how-to-code-in-python.pdf). When trying to run hadoop command for wordcount it shows an error

java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /input/input

[image: Hadoop error image]

What is the exact error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list the contents of the folder

```
hdfs dfs -ls /input
```

Look at everything not a file

Then remove the folder(s) listed in the error as not files

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R /input/input
```

Then upload your data again

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal file.txt /input/
```

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and found that there was a folder named input in my hdfs. Thank you for the answer.